# Output the rendered contents of a page on a JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, logging, error-handling

I'm having problems with getting decent JavaScript error invormation in a Production environment.

When I'm developing I can just attach a debugger and (usually) fix the problem.

When I get the same error in a production environment however at best I see is an error report that looks like this:

> Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
>   Url:   SomePage
>   Line:  42
>   Char:  13

Which doesn't help me very much - I can't see the rendered page and so I have no idea what line 42 looks like.

**Is there any way for me to log the entire *rendered* page contents whenever an error like this occurs?** (So line 42 of the output is the line where the error occured)

While I'm at it, are there any other techniques that I can use to help with getting useful error information from JavaScript (without need to break into the debugger) - failing that is there any way that I can structure my JavaScript slightly differently to help getting decent debug information?

I'm predominantly interested in IE - this is the browser that tends to cause me most problems.

Comment: I don't understand which environnement you use. If it's only with IE (ouch !), do you have installed debugbar (http://www.debugbar.com/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to get the exact original HTML source of the page back in all pages and all browsers.

Regarding debugging, you could use a logging library such as [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/) (disclaimer: I wrote it) and intersperse logging calls in your code. log4javascript enables you to send logging messages back to the server via Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, IE has by default the most utterly useless error reporting. The script and line number reported in the error are essentially guaranteed to be absolutely wrong. You can, however, install the [IE developer tool bar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) (for IE7 and older, it's built into IE8) from Microsoft, which can help track down the error source.